# Magento 2 custom module admin field output must be true

Tags: magento2, php, module, admin, extensions

I want to add a filed in the Magento 2 admin panel, this field must return in the frontend True if in admin is selected Yes. I try to add this in the system.xml:

```
<field id="do_something" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="5" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
    <label>Do something?</label>
    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
    <comment>Do we want to do something?</comment>
</field>
```

but this is return only 1 and 0 value and I need to have true or false;

What I can do?

Thank you

**Update:**

```
<?php if ($config->getDoSomething()): ?>'<?php echo $config->getDoSomething(); ?>',<?php else: ?><?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: you can treat 1 as true and 0 false, or if you want true/false directly you have to create your custom source model

Comment: thanks how I can treat 1 as true?

Comment: how are you using this value in frontend ? please add code

Comment: please take a look I update my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code

```
<?php $doSomething = ($config->getDoSomething() ? 'true' : 'false') ?>
<?php echo $doSomething; ?>'
```